# Way to use Fusion Tables with the Google Maps API while maintaining privacy?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, privacy

It's my understanding that the only way to use a private Fusion Table with the Maps API is if you're using the Business version of the API. Only public and unlisted tables can be used normally. I would really like to realize the performance benefits of Fusion Tables but am not interested in paying for a business license.

My question is this: How secure could an unlisted table be? The data I'll be displaying is sensitive, but not critical. It is unlikely to be sought out specifically, or scraped by a bot. (no addresses, names of people, phone numbers, etc).

If Fusion Tables really won't be an option for me and my sensitive data, with MySQL at what point would I start to see serious degradation based on the number of markers in an average browser? I estimate the maximum number of points in the table to be somewhere around 1000-2000.

Comment: MySQL won't be any more secure than FusionTables (probably less secure).

Answer (score 0):

The privacy-setting(public or unlisted) are only required for a FusionTableLayer.

You may use 2 Tables: 1 FusionTable(public or unlisted) to store the geometry and plot the markers, and a 2nd table(private) where you store the sensitive data. Use a common key for the rows, so you'll be able to request the sensitive data from table#2 based on the key returned by table#1.

Which kind of table you use for table#2 depends on you, data in a private FusionTable are accessible after Authentication, but I would prefer my own (mySQL)DB for sensitive data(It happens to me that the data of a FT was accessible via the FT-API, although the download-option was disabled, so I currently wouldn't rely too much in the security-- note that FusionTables are still experimental ).

Comment: "It happens to me that the data of a FT was accessible via the FT-API, although the download-option was disabled" is disturbing :-)  Can you send and email to googletables-feedback@google.com with the details?

Comment: In my case the sensitive data is the location data of the markers themselves (coordinates). Does your solution preclude this from working? Don't the locations need to be in the FT in order for the automatic tile rendering to occur?

Comment: *Does your solution preclude this from working?* Yes, it does. But I wonder why/how you want to visualize sensitive data when you don't want to expose these data.

Comment: I want to share a visualization of location data with a small community who it's safe to share it with.